# java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099;

Tags: java, server, rmi

I am writing a Java RMI program to calculate the factorial of a number.

This is the interface:

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface FactorialRMI extends Remote{

    public void setNumber(int val) throws RemoteException;
    public int calculateFactorial() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Then this is the class that implements the interface:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class FactorialRMIImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements FactorialRMI{
    private int number;
    public FactorialRMIImpl(String name) throws RemoteException {
        super();
        try {
            Naming.rebind("myFactorial",this);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setNumber(int val) throws RemoteException {
        this.number=val;
    }

    @Override
    public int calculateFactorial() throws RemoteException {
        int p=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=this.number;i++)
            p=p*i;
        return p;
    }

}
```

Here is the server code:

```
public class FactorialRMIServer {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            FactorialRMIImpl myFactorial=new FactorialRMIImpl("myFactorial");
            System.out.println("Server is ready...");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the client code:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.util.*;

public class FactorialRMIClient {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            FactorialRMI myFact=(FactorialRMI)Naming.lookup("myFactorial");
            Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number to calculate its factorial: ");
            int n=scan.nextInt();
            myFact.setNumber(n);
            System.out.println("The factorial of this number is: "+myFact.calculateFactorial());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am not using eclipse.
i am required to run this program in the bin folder of the jdk.
i am using jdk1.8

to compile the java file i put these file in the bin folder and run the command:

```
javac *.java
```

then i run the commands

```
rmic FactorialRMIImpl
start rmiregistry
start java FactorialRMIServer
start java FactorialRMIClient
```

in the last 2 command i get this error:

```
Exception: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The command `start rmiregistry` gives me an error:

```
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:220)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl$2.run(RegistryImpl.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl$2.run(RegistryImpl.java:193)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:689)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:873)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:193)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl$5.run(RegistryImpl.java:531)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl$5.run(RegistryImpl.java:529)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:689)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.createRegistry(RegistryImpl.java:528)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.main(RegistryImpl.java:551)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:132)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:386)
at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:248)
at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:140)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324)
... 15 more
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The RMI Registry is already running, or something else that is illegitimately using the same port. NB 'I am required to run this program in the bin folder of the jdk': whoever set this requirement doesn't know what he is talking about.

Comment: NB Your API design is poor. It would not support multiple clients correctly. You only need one method: `calculateFactorial(int number)`, and you don't need the `number` field.

Answer (score 5):

if you are running on windows, you can find the process running on port and kill that process using below command, so that port will be freed

```
netstat -ano | findstr :1099
taskkill /pid "EnterProcessIdHere" /F
```

For linux

```
lsof -i :1099
kill EnterProcessIdHere
```

Comment: i have tried this command "netstat -ano | findstr :1099" but nothing is showing

Comment: that's helped me, thx!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as this: if you use port number 8080 for RMI-related codes, you will never get this kind of error.

Comment: Yes you will. Tomcat uses that port. There are no ports that are magically free. Port 1099 was reserved for RMI in 1995, and there is no reason not to use it. Anything *else* that is using it is wrong, by definition. Most likely an RMI Registry was already running, and maybe you can just use that one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I know you’re a bot but that is nonsense. The answer is incorrect and could not be improved in any way other than complete rewrite or deletion.